# How to extract a part of string match with specific pattern but for all cases in a row and separate them by comma using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I've a pandas dataframe like below df including some string with different row size. i need just a part of this string with format match with `[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}`like T7114.

```
                       NODE
====================================================
T7114 (Shahrekord)
T7374 (Esfahan - Shahrekord Rd.), T7114 , T7113
T8319 (HOUMEH Shahrekord), E1826 (Shahrekord)
E1577 (Shahrekord), T7114 (Shahrekord), T7941 (KIAN)
T8319 (HOUMEH Shahrekord), T7941 (KIAN)
T7941 (KIAN), T7114 (Shahrekord)
```

how can i extract just this part from all the string each row and put them in inside each other by seperating using comma like below df?

```
                NODE                                             NE
============================================          ============================
T7114 (Shahrekord)                                             T7114
T7374 (Esfahan - Shahrekord Rd.),T7114,T7113              T7374,T7114,T7113
T8319 (HOUMEH Shahrekord), E1826 (Shahrekord)                T8319,E1826
E1577 (Shahrekord), T7114 (Shahrekord), T7941 (KIAN)      E1577,T7114,T7941
T8319 (HOUMEH Shahrekord), T7941 (KIAN)                     T8319,T7114
T7941 (KIAN), T7114 (Shahrekord)                            T7941,T7114
```

i tried to extract it using a regex with extract and strip function like below but it is only extracting the first match string while i want to extract all each row and separate them using comma. what is the most efficient way to do this?

```
df['NODE'] = df['NODE'].str.extract('([A-Z{1}0-9{4} ]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
df["NODE"].str.findall("\w\d+").str.join(",")
```

---

```
0                T7114
1    T7374,T7114,T7113
2          T8319,E1826
3    E1577,T7114,T7941
4          T8319,T7941
5          T7941,T7114
Name: NODE, dtype: object
```